# Integrate framework that uses CocoaPods to build into existing project

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, cocoapods

I have an existing iOS project.  I want to use a framework that I found on Github where the readme says to build it using CocoaPods.  I downloaded the framework, went into its directory and from the terminal entered "pod install".  This seems to have pulled in all the dependencies.  However, this is just an empty framework with a Pods folder that has all the dependencies in there.  There's no main file in this project.

I created a new project (iOS app) where I want to pull in this framework.  There are over a 100 different files.  What's the easiest/recommended way?

Comment: copy the `podfile` content into new project's podfile and then install

Comment: To install just type in the terminal (when you're in the project's folder) pod install